# How do I sort the rows in a nested object form in rails for just one view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When working with a nested model in a form, is there a way to sort the nested models in the view or in the controller? The closest answer I could find was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942267/sort-nested-objects-in-rails-2-3), but both of those solutions involve putting sort orders in the model. I'd rather avoid changing things fundamentally like that and keep this particular sort order to just one page.

Answer (score 0):

You can always sort with ruby: `parent.children.sort{|a,b| a.field <=> b.field}` or something like that
Or you can add a find method to parent model, like `def self.find_ordered_by_field`
Can't think of another options...

Answer (score 0):

Putting the sort in the models is absolutely the way to go.  You shouldn't have any more ruby code than necessary in your views themselves, because it's much harder to test that your sorting is working the way you think it should.

When you add the sort at the model level (and either answer in the link you posted works well) you can add an automated test to verify that it is, in fact, sorting the way you'd like.  This is business logic, and it belongs in the model.

Sometimes, however, you're looking to sort in a way that is NOT what you would normally want for this model.  Maybe you normally want them sorted by name, but in this one view you want them sorted newest to oldest.  At the very least, do the sort in the controller so once again it can be fully tested.  But I would still put it in the model, personally.

Comment: How can I sort in the controller, if I choose to go that route?

Comment: You can use the sort method the way Devenv recommended in his answer, and pass it to a global variable (@children = parent.children.sort...)